# Unable to send list of item from VueJS form

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, vuejs2, django-forms

I have vueJS application, calling patch to update user profile, below example I am trying to update the field **cities**

I have built serializer and views.py by using postman, during the development used postman to call patch method to update user profile, see below command. patch always work from postman api call

```
"cities": [
        "SANTA CLARA",
        "MILPITAS"
    ]
```

After the development I am trying to integrate with VueJS app, here passing cities from text box see the code

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label for="">Prefered Cities to work</label>
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            ref="cities_input"
                            id="cities"
                             v-model="userDetails.cities"
                          />
```

In form save action call below for set function

```
 formData.set("cities", this.$refs.cities_input.value);
```

If I provide only one city in text box, values getting updated to DB happily, but I provide more than one city in text box example  "SANTA CLARA","MILPITAS", or  SANTA CLARA,MILPITAS values not getting updated in DB, any help highly appreciated

Then I tried to hardcode in save action like below, but still not saving

```
formData.set("cities", [ "SANTA CLARA","MILPITAS"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed with below code

```
      var cityArray =  (this.$refs.cities_input.value).split(',')
      for (var i = 0; i < cityArray.length; i++) {
            formData.append('cities', cityArray [i]);
      }
```